# Dictionary to "inherit" from class of objects that I use it to store; e.g. my_dict['item1'].method1() or mydict['item1'].property1 = 'new'

Tags: python, class, dictionary, pycharm

I've searched for couple days now but couldn't find anything so maybe it's not possible.

As in topic, is there a way for a dict to "inherit" from a class so all the methods and properties are visible via "intelisens" ?

Example

```
class Word(object):
    def __init__(self, word):
        self.word = word
        self.base_word = ''
        self.derived_words = set()
        self.sub_words = set()
        self.frequency = 0

    def method_1(self):
        do something here

    def method_2(self):
        do something else here

myDict['computer'] = Word('computer')
myDict['notebook'] = Word('notebook')
```

and then i can obviously do this and it will work

```
mydict['computer'].method_2()
mydict['notebook'].frequency = 12
```

but i'd like to know if there is a way to make myDict object know that this methods and properties of the object are available and they would show up in "intelisense".

[Picture Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWtRO.png)

I'm using PyCharm.

Best regards
Bartek

Comment: I can't reproduce this. My PyCharm shows me what is available.

Comment: I've just added screenshot example.
You mean that in box marked in red you see all the methods and properties of the class Word ?

Comment: `myDict['computer']` will return a Word object (since thats what you put in it), and has all the methods/properties you want. This should work as you write it. Your title doesn't make sense, it implies `myDict.method_2()` as something that makes sense. `myDict[someString]` **is not** a `dict` (in the general class, you could have one in there).

Comment: I agree on the title side.
I know that it will work as I wrote it in the post but how to make it visible in intelisense.

Comment: Just add type hint to `d` definition. It will be like `d = {}  # type: typing.Dict[str, Word]` or `d: typing.Dict[str, Word] = {}` (since Python 3.6)

Comment: @user2235698
It works perfectly, Thank You

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm does support [type hinting](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/type-hinting-in-pycharm.html). I'm assuming you are using Python 2.7 since you are inheriting `object`. I have 3 ways you could do this in Python 2.7.

## 1

```
myDict['computer'] = Word('computer')
computer1 = myDict['computer'] # type: Word
```

## 2

```
computer2 = myDict['computer']
""":type : Word """
```

Now when you use `computer1` or `computer2` you should get the drop down that you like.

## 3

If your dictionary always returns a `Word` object you could create a dict object which inherits from `dict`, and make a function which returns `Word` type using `rtype` in the method docstring.

```
class Word(object):
    def __init__(self, word):
        self.word = word
    def foo(self):
        return self.word
class FooDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *arg, **kw):
        super(FooDict, self).__init__(*arg, **kw)
    def get_item(self, item):
        """
        My docstring.
        :return: a class of the type I want.
        :rtype: Word
        """
        return self[item]
a = Word("foo")    
d = FooDict()
d['computer'] = a
computer3 = d.get_item('computer')
```

Now `computer3` should behave how you like.

Comment: I actually used Python 3.5 and now installed 3.6 to be able to use typing hint but thx for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Reposting user2235698 answer from comment to my first post, for future googlers

Just add type hint to d definition. 
It will be like d = {} # type: typing.Dict[str, Word] or d: typing.Dict[str, Word] = {} (since Python 3.6) – user2235698 21 hours ago

so now code looks like this:

```
import typing

class Word():
    def __init__(self, word):
        self.word = word
        self.base_word = ''
        self.derived_words = set()
        self.sub_words = set()
        self.meaning = ''
        self.reading = ''
        self.frequency = ''
        self.sub_chars = set()

    def analyze_sub_words(self):
        print('working')

myComputer = Word('computer')
d: typing.Dict[str, Word] = {}
d['computer'] = myComputer
# now hints are being displayed
d['computer'].base_word
```